# Device Orientation - Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, device-orientation

I have a question regarding obtaining the Tilt Left-to-Right and Tilt Front-to-Back of a device.

I am using the following formula to obtain the tilt angle in degrees by converting the values obtained from the accelerometer to degrees:

`var tiltLR = Math.round(((acceleration.x) / 9.81) * -90); 

var tiltFB = Math.round(((acceleration.y + 9.81) / 9.81) * 90 * facingUp);`

[image]

The above holds ground when the mobile is in portrait mode.  However, I have an issue that can't seem to understand when the mobile is in landscape mode.

Imagine the mobile is rotated as in the following image:
[image]

I am guessing that the axis would change accordingly, so if in portrait mode that x-axis was the left-right of mobile and y-axis shows how close/far the mobile is from you, these would become:

x: up/down
y: left/right
z: close/far

Therefore, does it make sense that the variables in the landscape mode change to this?  Or im not visualising properly?

`var tiltLR = Math.round(((acceleration.y) / 9.81) * -90); 

var tiltFB = Math.round(((acceleration.z + 9.81) / 9.81) * 90 * facingUp);`

**EDIT** 
Or it should be as below??
`var tiltLR = Math.round(((acceleration.y) / 9.81) * -90); 

var tiltFB = Math.round(((acceleration.x + 9.81) / 9.81) * 90 * facingUp);`